# High Disk Usage on Windows 10

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, memory

I have a Dell Inspiron Core i5 with 4 GB RAM and 500 GB hard disk. After upgrading to windows 10 from 8.1, I am constantly facing a high disk usage problem which is causing my machine to run a ot slower than usual. The processes that usually have a high disk usage are as follows:

1. Antimalware service executable
2. System and compressed memory

Is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: don't use Windows defender, install a 3rd party Anti-Virus tool

Comment: i was using avira up until now. The same problem was there too.

Comment: Install the WPT (part of the Win10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk), run WPRUI.exe, select **First Level**, **CPU usage**, **DiskIO**, **FileIO** and click to start. Now capture 1 minute of the DiskIO. After 1 minute click on **Save**. Zip the large ETL file into zip/RAR file, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here.

Comment: do i need to install the entire sdk? its a 2.5 gb installation.

Comment: only the Windows Performance Toolkit

Comment: Not really an answer but I have had the same experience with about 5 other computers which I have upgraded. After a day or two the high disk usage was gone - I don't know though what is causing it. Never had this problem again. How long are you using windows 10 now?

Comment: Using it for over a year now. The problem was always there but its getting really bothersome these days. Cant work without something or the other crashing every other second.

Comment: have you instaleld only the WPT and captured the trace?

Comment: @magicandre1981 yeah, Here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-LesTcmHNFySFJHSi1xdktBQWs/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trace shows that the Antimalware service (Windows Defender) is causing most disk IO and here it hangs at scanning the MFT (Master File Table) and reading data from the pagefile:

[image]

For me Defender/Microsoft Security Essentials were always slow and I never used them. Also try a different AV suite.

Comment: You mean i should just get another software instead of defender? Which would you recommend(a free one preferably)?

Comment: try AvastFree or Avira AntiVir

Comment: I was using avira till now. It also had a high disk  usage

Comment: try Avast and look if you also see the high Disk usage

Comment: okay. Going to do that now.

Comment: Installing avast helped with the anti malware process but the 'system and compressed memory' process is still using 100% disk

Comment: capture/share a new diskIO trace when you see the 100% Disk usage.

Comment: have you captured a new trace when using Avast

Comment: hey sorry for the late reply. Nothing helped with the disk usage issue, so i went ahead and upgraded my ram from 4GB to 8 GB and that has brought down the disk usage for now.

Comment: @AbhishekAgarwal ok, thanks for the reply. More RAM causes less paging so yeah, this improves the situation

Answer (score 0):

You can hit <kbd>Ctr</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> and when task manager opens press the startup tab and you can disable processes that aren't necessary and have high impact.

Answer (score 0):

> **System and compressed memory**

i have seen this problem and 1 answer was **disable all notifications and aplications** go to settings, system, notifications and aplications and turn off all notifications (worked for me) and  this http://appuals.com/100-disk-usage-by-system-and-compressed-memory-in-windows-10/

and for

> **Antimalware service executable**

see the software credentials in properties and see if is a legit software if not
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> En task, find the file location an delete it and see if the program is in startup (i use CCleaner to clean/delete startup programs)

Good luck man  hope it works

Answer (score 0):

I had to fix a Dell laptop today which was showing 100% Disk Usage. The issue got resolved when we switched the Power Plan to Balanced. It was running with Dell power mode which spiked up the CPU. The task manager was showing some other services and processes though.

Go to Power Options > Select Balanced (recommended) Setting